# Salesforce - Sync with a public calendar via Salesforce Outlook Connector

Tags: outlook, salesforce, synchronization, outlook-calendar

I have Exchange 2010 and Outlook 2010.  I am trying to sync a public Outlook calendar with Salesforce using the Salesforce.  According to Idea Exchange ([here](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?c=09a30000000D9xtAAC&id=08730000000Jhw5AAC) and [here](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?c=09a30000000D9y3AAC&category=Outlook&id=08730000000HWk1&p=2&returnUrl=%2Fapex%2FideaList%3Fc%3D09a30000000D9y3AAC&sort=top)), it's not possible (although the second link does contain a workaround that uses a Salesforce license).  When I install the Salesforce Outlook Connector and select the calendar to sync with, I only see my personal calendar under my email address, not any public calendars.  If I select a "New" and navigate to the public calendar and try to create a sub-folder, I get a message saying "Could not create new folder: MAPI_E_NO_ACCESS"

How can I sync this public folder? If this would show under my email address, I could just select it.  Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't an immediate solution you could vote up the ideas:

[IdeaExchange: make Public Calendar events first-class citizens](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?c=09a30000000D9xtAAC&id=08730000000BrqhAAC)

[IdeaExchange: Salesforce for Outlook: Enable synching to public folder](https://sites.secure.force.com/success/ideaView?c=09a30000000D9xtAAC&id=08730000000Jhw5AAC)

API access to public calendars should make this possible.